# onSaveInstanceState() and onPause()

Tags: android

I'm a little bit confused about these two methods in Android.

From the documentation I understand that `onSaveInstanceState()` should be called to store only temporary information, and `onPause()` should be used to store any persistent data.

I was wondering why to call `onSaveInstance()` at all, when `onPause()` is called every time. Then I read in the Notepad tutorial:

> "Note that `saveState()` must be
>   called in both `onSaveInstanceState()`
>   and `onPause()` to ensure that the
>   data is saved. This is because there
>   is no guarantee that
>   `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called
>   and because when it is called, it is
>   called before `onPause()`."

There is no guarantee that `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called because you can simply walk out of the activity using the back button.

But according to this if you don't save the persistent data inside both methods, the app might be killed while inside `onSaveInstanceState()`.

So we need to save the persistent data in both methods actually, am I right?

But if this is true, isn't this too much of an overhead and maybe there should be some other additional flag to tell if the method is already called or something?

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

Answer (score 20):

From the developer guide on [activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html):

> Note: Because **onSaveInstanceState()** is not guaranteed to be called,
>   you should use it only to record the **transient state** of the activity
>   (the state of the UI)—you should never use it to store persistent
>   data. Instead, you should use **onPause()** to store **persistent data** (such
>   as data that should be saved to a database) when the user leaves the
>   activity.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState() is not guaranteed to be called` now that's some crazy bullshit! why bother having it at all then ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Maybe it was not true back in 2013? Currently from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle) I infer it is guaranteed - you're right now.

Answer (score 11):

`onSaveInstanceState()` is meant to "remember" the current state when a configuration change occurs like e.g. a screen orientation change. This is not meant for "long term persistence".

In the notepad example this may be the same in both cases. In other applications, like e.g. a Twitter client, the data itself may be persisted in a background service. In `onCreate()` some items are pulled from the DB and displayed and e.g. the current position is remembered. When an orientation change occurs, this "current position" could be remembered in `onSaveInstanceState()` and later in `onCreate()` after the orientation change be used to display the message the user has last looked at.

See also [this guide](http://developer.android.com//guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can save non-view instance state ("internal state such as user preferences") on a soft kill (orientation change) in `onSaveInstanceState` using bundles and on a hard kill (back button while we are in focus) in `onStop` using preferences. If you have other data ("shared document-like data -- typically stored in a SQLite database using a content provider"), you should do this in `onPause`.